# How to escape special characters in Ansible regex?

Tags: ansible

I have a file that contains the following `$${local_ip_v4}`. I need to replace it with the actual IP of my computer. I have created the following task but not sure how to make it match. I cant seem to figure out how to escape the "`{}`".

```yaml
vars:
  floatingIP: 1.1.1.1

  - name:  "Fix sip_profiles to listen on floating IP"
    replace:
      path: /etc/freeswitch/sip_profiles/internal.xml
      regexp: "$${local_ip_v4}"
      replace: "{{ floatingIP }}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use double backslashes, please see below the task.

```yaml
  - name:  "Fix sip_profiles to listen on floating IP"
    replace:
      path: /php_basedir/ANSIBLE/ANSIBLE_TESTS/testfile.txt
      regexp: "\\$\\$\\{local_ip_v4\\}"
      replace: "{{ floatingIP }}"
```

I added backslashes to the `$`, as it has a special meaning in regex, while you want to catch the character`$`.

Comment: Or use the much more sane [`| regex_escape`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#regular-expression-filters)

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: The solution below is a generic solution when **both** the `regexp` and `replace` arguments can contain *any* special characters.

You can use [`regex_escape()`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#regular-expression-filters) to **escape the regex pattern**, i.e. the string used in the *`regexp`* part, and you can use `regex_replace("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\")` to safely escape the *`replace`* part (keep in mind that the replacement pattern is not a regular expression! If you escape it with `regex_escape`, some unexpected (special) characters might come out with backslashes in front of them).

So your fixed code will look like

```
vars:
  floatingIP: 1.1.1.1
  localIP: $${local_ip_v4}

  - name:  "Fix sip_profiles to listen on floating IP"
    replace:
      path: /etc/freeswitch/sip_profiles/internal.xml
      regexp: '{{ localIP | regex_escape() }}'
      replace: '{{ floatingIP | regex_replace("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\") }}'
```